# Is there any way to get notified when API Gateway timeouts?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudwatch

I have an API that sometimes goes in timeout, because the response did not return before the 30 seconds limit. On CloudWatch I see the log for the timeout, but is there a way to set an alarm or something that notifies me when this occurs (for instance: send and email when the response is a timeout)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see the event in the CloudWatch logs, you can create a [Metric Filter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CountOccurrencesExample.html) on the log entry. This will create a CloudWatch metric, and on that, you can create an alarm.

Also, API Gateway will publish a set of metrics by default under `AWS/ApiGateway` namespace. [Doesn't look like they have a timeout count metric](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-metrics-and-dimensions.html), but you could alarm on fault rate (`5XXError`) or latencies (`IntegrationLatency`, `Latency`).